# UILabel that is part of custom UITableViewCell text not updating in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

The text for my `UILabel`s will not update. Here are the `UITableViewController` delegate functions:

```
#import "PoolsTableViewController.h"

@interface PoolsTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation PoolsTableViewController

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self.items addObject:@"Hello"];
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PoolsTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.items count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %li, %@", (long)indexPath.row, [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    PoolsTableViewCell *cell = (PoolsTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.cellLeftViewLabel.text = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.cellRightViewLabel.text = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I try and change the text to the string that is contained in `self.items`. The log output is:

`indexPath.row: 0, Hello`

So I know that it is actually there before I try to change the `UILabel` text. This is what my custom `UITableViewCell` looks like:

**PoolsTableViewCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PoolsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellLeftViewLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellRightViewLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellLeftImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellRightImageView;

@end
```

**PoolsTableViewCell.m**

```
#import "PoolsTableViewCell.h"

@implementation PoolsTableViewCell
@synthesize cellLeftViewLabel;
@synthesize cellRightViewLabel;
@synthesize cellLeftImageView;
@synthesize cellRightImageView;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
    cellLeftViewLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cellRightViewLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cellLeftViewLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cellRightViewLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Everything is linked correctly in the `Interface Builder` I think:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Screen after breakpoint and breakpoint settings:

[image]

Comment: Have you connected the labels in your nib to the outlets in your cell class

Comment: yes ill post a screenshot

Comment: what do you actually see when you run your code?  Do you see the placeholder "label" text? Try lines = 1, if that works,  check your constraints.

Comment: yes I see the placeholder "Label" text, so that means the constraints are ok correct? and `numberOfLines=0`? I believe i tried `= 1` already.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and step through to make sure nothing is `nil`, unlike Swift, Objective-C happily does nothing if you send a message to `nil`

Comment: with setting the breakpoint am i checking that `cell != nil` for the condition? I'm not exactly sure how to interpret the output when it hits the breakpoint, the cell doesn't load and in the code it has `Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1` just below the line I set the breakpoint on, for the breakpoint condition i used `cell != nil` although im not really sure what im doing with these settings

Comment: posting a picture of my screen

Comment: if I do `cell == nil` for the condition it gets through...so it seems that the `Cell` that it dequeues is not `nil`?

Comment: this is also my first time really trying to use storyboards instead of doing everything programatically and i just noticed that if I remove the item from `self.items` it still renders the cell, am i doing something wrong in my `main.storyboard`? I remember skimming over making a "prototype" cell, but I thought that just meant making one cell as a `xib` and inserting it into the `main.storyboard` to be referenced.

Comment: do i even need the `PoolsTableViewCell` in the `main.storyboard`? or is my code referencing the custom `PoolsTableViewCell` `nib`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186436/discussion-between-paulw11-and-ewizard).

Comment: Here is a tutorial I wrote about using UITableView. It might help you: https://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2017/11/how-to-create-reusable-views-with.html